# How to install Slick2d in Netbeans

Tags: java, installation, netbeans-7, slick2d

I have been searching for quite a bit now but I have never been able to figure out how to install Slick2d into netbeans 7 on windows. Every search I have done has given me bad results and errors in my projects. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can't this question be narrowed down to "How do I enable Scala support in my IDE?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking hard enough?

http://ray3k.com/site/tutorials/tutorial-setup-slick-in-netbeans/

http://wiki.netbeans.org/SlickSet

Download Link: http://slick.cokeandcode.com/downloads/slick.zip

Slick Nightly Build: https://www.newdawnsoftware.com/hudson/view/Slick/job/Slick/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/Slick/dist/slick.zip

This link warns you of a security exception because they use an untrusted certificate. Just add an exception and you can access the link.

Comment: I checked that website out when I tried to download the website gave an error.(I downloaded the build from the original website)